# One virtual machine, multiple hosted websites

Tags: domain, ip, virtual-machines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find other domains hosted on an IP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/297662/how-can-i-find-other-domains-hosted-on-an-ip)

I have a simple question: 
Is there a possibility, knowing only the virtual server's IP and one domain name, to determine the rest of the domains hosted on that server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of methods for learning many of the domains hosted, but neither will work for all of them.

First you can sniff the traffic going to that IP address and look for HTTP GET requests and filter out all of the domains. If you have network access to do this, you can learn a lot of the domains. However any domains that don't get any traffic won't show up on your list.

Alternatively you can use some of the reverse ip tools from sites like domaintools. Which parse results of domains that have pointed to that IP address via known DNS servers. These are also incomplete results, frequently they show sites which used to be hosted there but are not hosted any more. It can give you a good basic idea.